# Unable to deploy my code to google cloud app engine via gitlab

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gitlab-ci, gcloud, app-engine-flexible

I am trying to create a gitlab pipeline for deploying my spring boot app to google app engine and i am able to authenticate app engine to gitlab but at deployment step of ci file i am getting Java 7+ JRE must be installed and on your system PATH though i have installed it with gcloud install components app-engine-java command in gitlab ci file. Please suggest what needs to be done to resolve this error.

**.gitlab-ci.yml file:**

```
image: google/cloud-sdk:alpine

            deploy_production:
              stage: deploy
              environment: Production
              only:
              - master
              script:
              - echo $DEPLOY_KEY_FILE_PRODUCTION > /tmp/$CI_PIPELINE_ID.json
              - gcloud -q components install app-engine-java
              - gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file /tmp/$CI_PIPELINE_ID.json
              - gcloud --quiet --project $PROJECT_ID_PRODUCTION --verbosity debug app deploy src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml
```

Below are the debug details which mentions that to use the local staging for java, java JRE must be installed though i have installed it using gcloud install components google-app-engine cmd:

```
$ gcloud --quiet --project $PROJECT_ID_PRODUCTION --verbosity debug app deploy src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml
            DEBUG: Running [gcloud.app.deploy] with arguments: [--project: "playground-kg", --quiet: "True", --verbosity: "debug", DEPLOYABLES:1: "[u'src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml']"]
            **DEBUG: (gcloud.app.deploy) To use the local staging for java, a Java 7+ JRE must be installed and on your system PATH**
            Traceback (most recent call last):
              File "/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/cli.py", line 983, in Execute
                resources = calliope_command.Run(cli=self, args=args)
              File "/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/backend.py", line 784, in Run
                resources = command_instance.Run(args)
              File "/google-cloud-sdk/lib/surface/app/deploy.py", line 90, in Run
                parallel_build=False)
              File "/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/command_lib/app/deploy_util.py", line 573, in RunDeploy
                args.deployables, stager, deployables.GetPathMatchers())
              File "/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/command_lib/app/deployables.py", line 334, in GetDeployables
                service = Service.FromPath(path, stager, path_matchers)
              File "/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/command_lib/app/deployables.py", line 102, in FromPath
                service = matcher(path, stager)
              File "/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/command_lib/app/deployables.py", line 175, in AppengineWebMatcher
                staging_dir = stager.Stage(descriptor, app_dir, 'java-xml', env.STANDARD)
              File "/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/command_lib/app/staging.py", line 387, in Stage
                return command.Run(self.staging_area, descriptor, app_dir)
              File "/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/command_lib/app/staging.py", line 171, in Run
                args = self.GetArgs(descriptor, app_dir, staging_dir)
              File "/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/command_lib/app/staging.py", line 251, in GetArgs
                return self._mapper(self.GetPath(), descriptor, app_dir, staging_dir)
              File "/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/command_lib/app/staging.py", line 107, in _JavaStagingMapper
                java_bin = java.RequireJavaInstalled('local staging for java')
              File "/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/command_lib/util/java.py", line 54, in RequireJavaInstalled
                v=min_version))
            JavaError: To use the local staging for java, a Java 7+ JRE must be installed and on your system PATH
            ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) To use the local staging for java, a Java 7+ JRE must be installed and on your system PATH
```

Answer (score 0):

Some people got the same issue trying to create the same workflow, but with github. The same issue can be viewed [here](https://github.com/actions/gcloud/issues/3). This guy solved this by adding openjdk-8 to Docker.

You can see [here](https://github.com/freddyboucher/gcloud/commit/3a1a1eef6b1d96c122ce5e59e3c19204d32a84d0) how to add openjdk-8 to Docker.

If this did not work for you, please let me know and I will try to edit my answer.

You may also want to check [Jenkins](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/jenkins-on-kubernetes-engine-tutorial) for Google Cloud and using [Jenkins with Gitlab](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/integration/jenkins.html) for CI. It may be helpful for your CI workflow.

Comment: I am not able to integrate this peace of code for installing jdk to my CI file. Can you help me integrating apt-get and gcloud cmds.

Comment: Could you please tell me how you are not able to integrate it? Show me some errors or logs. Note that you can run that script separately from your CI file.